# How to get all weeks in a month using Carbon

Tags: php, php-carbon

I want to return all weeks in a current month using carbon. So each week I want to return 2 dates. Please see my code below:

```
$dt = Carbon::now(); //or initialize it any other way
        
Carbon::setWeekStartsAt(Carbon::MONDAY);
Carbon::setWeekEndsAt(Carbon::SUNDAY);

$weeks += [
    'w1' => $dt->subDays($dt->dayOfWeek - 4)->format('Y-m-d H:i:s') . ' - ' . $dt->subDays($dt->dayOfWeek - 7)->format('Y-m-d H:i:s')
]; 

$weeks += [
    'w2' => $dt->subDays($dt->dayOfWeek - 3)->format('Y-m-d H:i:s') . ' - ' . $dt->subDays($dt->dayOfWeek - 7)->format('Y-m-d H:i:s')
]; 
$weeks += [
    'w3' => $dt->subDays($dt->dayOfWeek - 1)->format('Y-m-d H:i:s') . ' - ' . $dt->subDays($dt->dayOfWeek - 7)->format('Y-m-d H:i:s')
]; 

$weeks += [
    'w4' => $dt->subDays($dt->dayOfWeek - 1)->format('Y-m-d H:i:s') . ' - ' . $dt->subDays($dt->dayOfWeek - 7)->format('Y-m-d H:i:s')
];

return $weeks;
```

That code returns this:

```
"data": {
   "w1": "2020-08-27 06:45:01 - 2020-08-30 06:45:01",
   "w2": "2020-09-02 06:45:01 - 2020-09-06 06:45:01",
   "w3": "2020-09-07 06:45:01 - 2020-09-13 06:45:01",
   "w4": "2020-09-14 06:45:01 - 2020-09-20 06:45:01"
}
```

**What output I want**

```
"data": {
   "w1": "2020-08-03 06:09:06 - 2020-08-09 06:09:06",
   "w2": "2020-08-10 06:09:06 - 2020-08-16 06:09:06",
   "w3": "2020-08-17 06:09:06 - 2020-08-23 06:09:06",
   "w4": "2020-08-24 06:09:06 - 2020-08-30 06:09:06",
}
```

Comment: but there are no `w1` and `w4` in your source, so it doesn't follow that it would return your expected output

Comment: Furthermore, some months have 5 weeks. I can provide a solution to this but unfortunately it'll be a downvote magnet despite that it would work. Because I will just use a gregorian algorithm. Frowned upon to actually not rely on existing libs.

Comment: @GetSet Check my updates.

Comment: Just looked. Well if you consider that day of week is a value between inclusive 0 and 6, shouldnt you be using a "day" value on multiple of 7? As in w1 @ +0, w2 @ +7, w3  @ +14, and so on.

Comment: Also as i mentioned, some months have 5 weeks.

Comment: One important observation is that in your data the time part doesn't change. So if you know the amount of days in the month, then iteratively you can determine the weeks, provided you know the start day of week for the 1st of that month.

Comment: Disregard the time part. I will set it to `00:00:00` later on.

Comment: Well an iterative way will be to (1) determine day of week for the 1st of the month, (2) loop until end of month, (3) inside loop record when weeks start and end. I think i have some code for this and if i do, i will post.

Comment: Okay. Will try that one too.

Answer (score 0):

[SOLVED]

```
$data = [];

$get_week_dates = function($position){

    $start = date('d-m-Y', strtotime("{$position} Monday of this month"));
    $time = strtotime($start);
    $end = strtotime('next sunday, 12:00am', $time);
    $format = 'l, F j, Y g:i A';
    $end_day = date($format, $end);

    return [Carbon::parse($start)->format('m-d-Y'), Carbon::parse($end_day)->format('m-d-Y')];
};

$data += [
   'w1' => $get_week_dates('first'),
   'w2' => $get_week_dates('second'),
   'w3' => $get_week_dates('third'),
   'w4' => $get_week_dates('fourth')
];
```

Answer (score 0):

Let precise your context. As per your example, the fourth week may overlap the next month. And they might be a fifth Monday you want take into account.

So what you get here is not exactly what I would call "all weeks in a month" but rather the 4 first weeks (starting on a Monday) in the current month.

About your function, you can shorten it as getting date from time then time from date to set it as midnight is overkill and `Carbon::parse` handle the same syntax than `strtotime` and getting time makes no point if you trim to a date format:

```
$get_week_dates = function ($position) {
    $start = CarbonImmutable::parse("$position Monday of this month");

    return [$start->format('m-d-Y'), $start->next('Sunday, 12:00am')->format('m-d-Y')];
};
```

In the code above `, 12:00am` is kept if you have other formats to support but can be removed if you only use `m-d-Y`